# PaintComponent not showing up

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

i'm currently adding functionality and completing a Hang-Man game my programing teacher made.

I added a frame to enable the user to write their own word to play the game however i stumbled on the following problem.

The PaintComponent that is supposed to draw when the user guesses the wrong word does not work. it does not draw when i guess the wrong word. (right now the word to guess is set to "hello" but i am going to change it after PaintComponent works).

i have tried to put all the components including the object to a JPanel but after i tried to do that the JFrame did not show upp after i pressed the button (b).

should i try with JPanel again or can i do anything to solve it as it currently is. i would like to point out that my teachers original code does not have the components put into a JPanel, he only has a frame. However his class extends with JPanel.

Anny suggestions ?

```
package hangtest2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class HangTest2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    // frame intro skärm
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HangMan");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

    //label till orden
    JLabel intro = new JLabel();
    String ord = "Valfri";
    intro.setText(ord);
    Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 25);
    intro.setFont(font);

    
    
    //till att välja ord
    JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
    field.setFont(font);
    JButton b = new JButton("ok");
    b.setBounds(370, 300, 100, 30);
    
    frame.add(intro);
    frame.add(field);
    frame.add(b);
    frame.setBackground(Color.white);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
            
    
    // frame hang
    
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("HangMan");
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame2.setLayout(null);
    
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.setLayout(null);
    
    
    
    JLabel hang = new JLabel();
    String firstinstruct = "Gissa genom att Mata in en bokstav ";
    hang.setText(firstinstruct);
    Font font2 = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 10);
    hang.setFont(font2);
    hang.setBounds(70, 100, 600,150 );
    

    
    
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
    field2.setVisible(true);
    field2.setSize(300, 30);
    field2.setLocation(60, 300);
    field2.setVisible(true);
    

    JButton b2 = new JButton("ok");
    b2.setBounds(370, 300, 100, 30);
    
    frame2.add(b2);
    frame2.add(field2);
    frame2.add(hang);
    frame2.setBackground(Color.white);     
    frame2.setSize(600, 400);
    
    DynamicHangTest2 object = new DynamicHangTest2(field, field2, b, b2, frame, frame2);
    b.addActionListener(object);
    field.addActionListener(object); 
    b2.addActionListener(object);
    field2.addActionListener(object);   
    frame2.add(object);
    frame2.setVisible(false);
    
}

}
```

The Dynamic Class

```
package hangtest2;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class DynamicHangTest2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener {

private int error;
public static String a = "hello";
JFrame frame, frame2;
JButton b,b2;
JTextField field, field2; 

public DynamicHangTest2(JTextField field, JTextField field2, JButton b, JButton b2, JFrame frame, JFrame frame2) {
    
    this.frame = frame;
    this.frame2 = frame2;
    this.b = b; 
    this.b2 = b2;
    this.field = field;
    this.field2 = field2;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getX() + " " + e.getY());
    
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    Object source = e.getSource();
    
    if(source.equals(b)) {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    if (source.equals(b2)) {
        if (!a.contains(field2.getText())) {
            error++;
            frame2.repaint();
        }
        field2.setText("");
    }
    
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    if (error == 1)
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);

    if (error == 2) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
    }
    
    if (error == 3) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
    }
    
    if (error > 3) {
        Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 25);
        g.setFont(font);        
        g.drawString("GAME OVER", 270, 170);
    }
    
    

    
}

}
```

Comment: You have a problem with your layouts (GridLayout, AbsoluteLayout)... as soon as I changed the layout of frame2 to a GridLayout, your code worked as expected

Comment: `DynamicHangTest2` should override `getPreferredSize()` as a hint to the layout manager (mentioned by @JavaMan). Any override of a paint method should first call the `super` method.

Comment: Almost forgot: `frame2.setLayout(null);`Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).